# HiveQL: Union table is smaller than either component table

Tags: sql, hive

Why is the table resulting from the `UNION`of two tables smaller than either of the tables involved in the `UNION`?

```
CREATE TABLE adb.table4 STORED AS ORC AS
SELECT a.*
FROM adb.table2 a
UNION
SELECT b.*
FROM adb.table3 b;

hive> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM adb.table4;
15,961,225
Time taken: 0.084 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM adb.table2;
70,152,930
Time taken: 0.085 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM adb.table3;
39,384,833
```

Comment: because `union` eliminate duplicates and keeps one.

Answer (score -1):

You should try "Union ALL" not just Union....

There is a difference.  If memory serves me correctly.  Union only returns when the tables are found in both places.  Union all takes everything from either source regardless of a match in field name.